# Shared Service with Angular. How do I implement an observer?

Tags: angular

I have a component child which is a table with a button to add a new registry. With this example I want to emit an event with this Shared Service and the Component Parent is the observer of this Shared Service.
So with this example I can't catch the events and assign to the variable in Component Parent.
Anyone could explain how I can do this with Angular?

*Component Child:*

```
export class ComponentChild implements OnInit {


    constructor(
        private ss: SharedService,
    ) {
        this.ss = ss;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getData();
    }

    add() {
        this.ss.show();
    }
}
```

*SharedService*

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    @Output() fire: EventEmitter<any>;

    show() {
        this.fire.emit(true);
    }
}
```

*Component Parent*

```
export class ComponentParent implements OnInit {

    add: Boolean;
    subscription: any;

    constructor(
        private ss: SharedService,
    ) {
        this.ss = ss;
        this.ss.fire.subscribe(item => {
            this.add = item;
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than an `EventEmitter` (which is typically used to allow you to apply a function to the event in the component template which the *parent* component can listen to), use an observable such as `Subject`.

Your shared service doesn't have a parent, it's a singleton, so `EventEmitter` is inappropriate for this requirement.

So your service would be

```
fire: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

Then any component you want to make an observer can subscribe to changes to it.

```
this.ss.fire.subscribe((item: any) => {
    this.add = item;
}
```

Now any time the subject in SharedService has its value updated, your observer can update its local variable.